# Why is rsync copying directory structure when my find result only shows me files?

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync, find

I have an annoyingly complicated `find` command I've cobbled together that I pipe to `rsync` with the intention of copying files and syncing new versions. I'm trying to write something that is efficient enough to be run in `cron`.

```
find /home/archive/dir1/ -not -path '*/\.*' -ipath "/home/archive/dir1/*/*document-name*" -type f \( -iname "*.ods" -o -iname "*.pdf" \) -print0 | rsync -v --delete --files-from=- --from0 / /home/user/newdir2/
```

The idea is that it goes into a huge directory, pulls out the files that have filenames with `document-name` in the path.

The problem is it doesn't just copy files, it recursively copies all directory structure, when I simply want a all files returned from `find` to be collected into this separate directory.

I get exactly the result I want with:

```
find /home/archive/dir1/ -not -path '*/\.*' -ipath "/home/archive/dir1/*/*document-name*" -type f \( -iname "*.ods" -o -iname "*.pdf" \) -exec rsync -avz --delete {} /home/user/newdir2/ \;
```

Trouble is this spawns a billion `rsync` instances to do something that a single file list ought to do, probably not great for `cron`.

IE, this:

```
/home/archive/dir1/New1/New1 document-name.ods
/home/archive/dir1/New2/New2 document-name.pdf
/home/archive/dir1/New3/new3-DOCUMENT-NAME.ods
...
/home/archive/dir1/New9234/New9234-document-name.ods
```

Becomes:

```
/home/user/newdir2/New1 document-name.ods
/home/user/newdir2/New2 document-name.pdf
/home/user/newdir2/new3-DOCUMENT-NAME.ods
...
/home/user/newdir2/New9234-document-name.ods
```

Any suggestions on improving my command welcome.

[I have tried using exclude in rsync, but I do not think it's the right solution.](https://superuser.com/questions/436070/rsync-copying-directory-contents-non-recursively)

How can I *efficiently* sync all of these files?

Comment: Your `find` definitly not matches the `dir[1-9234]` given in your example. Are all files you want to search in `dir1`? As a side note: `-ipath` is depricated and should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My example was actually written out wrong, the command did exactly what I wanted it to when I ran it with -exec, so I knew that was at least CORRECT.

Comment: Also @Marcus, what do you recommend instead of -ipath or -path?

Comment: there is another bit: `/archive/dir1/...` in `ipath` must have the same root as the find location  `/home/archive/dir1/` to work properly. I assume it is `-ipath "/home/archive/dir1/*/*document-name*"`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a much more efficient way then finding files and execute a single instance of rsync. Any attampt to pipe a list of files into rsync will result in a maintained directory structure.

One alternative (if you can constraint the find pattern) is to use:

```
rsync -d --delete --include=*.pdf --include=*.ods --exclude=* /home/ms/archive/dir1/**/. /home/ms/newdir2/.
```

That will sync all pdf/ods-files of (sub-)directories with the folder /home/ms/newdir2/ without maintaining directories in a single rsync-structure.

Your given example (in case document-name or DOCUMENT-NAME) would be solved by using:

```
rsync -d --delete --include=*document-name.pdf --include=*DOCUMENT-NAME.pdf --include=*DOCUMENT-NAME.ods --include=*document-name.ods --include=*DOCUMENT-NAME.pdf --exclude=* /home/ms/archive/dir1/**/. /home/ms/newdir2/.
```

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate a regular expression or something for the spelling of document-name? I don't have complete control over the file naming so many of them end up DOcument-name or Document-NAME. It's impossible to guess all contingencies. Hence my use of the case insensitive flag in find.

Comment: The other problem with this is it syncs the hidden files that the find script trimmed out: `-not -path '*/\.*'`

Comment: Yes, I saw the flag. Unfortunately, you cannot use `regex` in `rsync`. As soon as you use `find` with `regex`, you will end up with the complete directory structure in you backup, except the case you call `rsync` for each found file individually (as you proposed in your question). I will keep the examples in case someone stumble upon the question and has more _static_ filenames.